# getLoginStatus not firing with calling from FB canvas

Tags: canvas, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-canvas

Attempting a client site authorization, and attempting to run within a canvas.  If I access the my website directly http://mysite.com/ everything works.  If I try to run via canvas https://apps.facebook.com/myapp it runs but getLoginStatus does not fire at all.

```
var curLoc = window.location;


 FB.init({
   appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // App ID
   channelUrl: curLoc.protocol + "//" + curLoc.hostname + ":" + curLoc.port + "/channel.html",
   cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
   status: true,
   oauth: true,
   xfbml: true
 });

 FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
   if (response.status === 'connected') {
     smloader.gameVariables.smUserid = response.authResponse.userID;
     facebook.isLoaded = true;
   } else {
     facebook.authUser();
   }

 }, true);
```

Login if needed.

```
function facebook.authUser() {
 FB.login(function (response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     smloader.gameVariables.smUserid = response.authResponse.userID;
     facebook.isLoaded = true;
   }
   else {
     facebook.authUser();
   }
 }, { scope: 'email,publish_actions' });
```

}

Once Facebook.isLoaded is true, I know we are logged in and ready to continue. but it never gets there directly from the canvas page.

I am in sandbox mode, currently running via http not https as I don't

Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I'm having the same issue right now

Comment: Do you get any errors in console? FB.init should be called in  `window.fbAsyncInit = function() {FB.init(...);}`

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing the same pb and this is how i fixed it :

Even if the getLoginStatus() works within your http website, the getLoginStatus() will not fire at all within the fb canvas unless **you provide a valid Secure Canvas URL** (https://yoursite.com/) !
It means you need to run your app on a https server (port 443)
If you do not want to buy a certificate you can create and self-signed a certificate (see here : http://greengeckodesign.com/blog/2013/06/15/creating-an-ssl-certificate-for-node-dot-js/)

I Hope this will help