# Facebook App: Javascript SDK getLoginStatus not working in canvas

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I have been racking my brain for 2 days now. I am trying to build a simple Facebook app using the Javascript SDK and I just want a simple alert if the user is not authorized using getLoginStatus(). It works fine in my website but not in the canvas. I get no alert. I am using very simple code that Facebook provides.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
// init the FB JS SDK
FB.init({
  appId      : '354932757968708',         // App ID from the app dashboard
  channelUrl : '//www.staging.socialdigi.com/channel.html', // Channel file 
  status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
  xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins
});

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
if (response.status === 'connected') {
  alert("Youre In");
  var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
  var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
} else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
  alert("Not Authorized");
} else {
  // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
}
});
};

// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

I get the following errors in the console but have been told it doesnt have anything to do with my issue

**Blocked a frame with origin "http://static.ak.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://staging.socialdigi.com". The frame requesting access set "document.domain" to "facebook.com", but the frame being accessed did not. Both must set "document.domain" to the same value to allow access.**

I do not have an ssl
Its in sandbox mode
I have the canvas url correct and nothing for secure canvas url
app id is correct

any help is appriciated
thanks

Comment: Same here. As usual FBs documentation/samples suck.

Comment: See answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12969633/getloginstatus-not-firing-with-calling-from-fb-canvas/23960249#23960249